# Calling Microsoft Graph from Google Appengine Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, microsoft-graph-api, google-oauth

I need to call the Microsoft Graph from a Google Appengine Python application, this requires oAuth2 authentication.

Google provide the Google API Client Libraries for calling their own REST api's (such as Calendar / Drive / Youtube etc) - is it possible to use the library to call other non Google REST API's such as Microsoft Graph?

If not has anyone used another library to do so from Appengine Python. You can not use the Microsoft supplied python SDK as this requires python version 3+ and Appengine only supports 2.7.

Thanks in advance,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

The authorization token you receive from Google will only work with their APIs. You'll need a separate token for use with Graph. For this you can use [ADAL library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/adal/).

Since you need to stick with 2.7, you'll need issue REST directly. The existing SDK (as you noted) requires py3. You may want to take a look at [restclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/restclient) for this. Its been a while since I've had to use this lib but I recall it really simplified calling REST endpoints.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, what I am asking is since the Google API Client Libraries use standard oauth2 to call Google API's has anyone overridden these libraries to call the Microsoft graph and obtain an authorization token (without having to write the whole thing from scratch) I was hoping to make use of the existing libraries?